# TypeError with dense block of Densenet in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement a Densenet in tensorflow. I want to rewrite this version [DenseNet](https://github.com/okason97/DenseNet-Tensorflow2/blob/master/densenet/densenet.py)
using subclassing API, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, <NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>] that don't all match.
```

So I guess that the problem is into my DenseBlock, where I use the Concat

```
class DenseBlock(Layer):

  def __init__(self, nb_layers, nb_filter, growth_rate, dropout_rate=None, grow_nb_filters=True, **kwargs):

    super(DenseBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.nb_layers = nb_layers
    self.growth_rate =growth_rate
    self.nb_filter = nb_filter
    self.grow_nb_filters = grow_nb_filters
    self.conv_blocks = [ConvBlock(growth_rate, dropout_rate) for i in range(nb_layers)]

  def call(self, inputs):
    concat_feat = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
    for conv in self.conv_blocks:

        x = conv
        concat_feat = tf.concat([concat_feat, x], -1)

        if self.grow_nb_filters:
            self.nb_filter += self.growth_rate

    return concat_feat, self.nb_filter
```

As last resort I tried to replace with a tf.keras.layer.concatenate(), but I got a NoneType error.

I hope that it's not duplicate question, but I only found the same error related to masking in LSTM.
This is where I think that is the error, but I want also to provide my notebook to give you more info [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10KxoCsSNwQNqG0eQe2EtIItEjbzxI7LE?usp=sharing)
Thank you in advance for your help